# Django Admin - dynamic select options with foreignkey and manytomanyfields

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Here the `supplier` is related to `Supplier` model (ForeignKey) and `substrate` is with `Substrate` (ManyToManyField). The main model here is `SupplierInfo` from which we can filter suppliers and get their respective `substrate`.

When ever admin clicks on the dropdown of `Arrival_supplier` and, `SupplierInfo_substrate` should be filtered with the `supplier name` and should be able to receive `SupplierInfo_substrate` inside `Arrival_substrate`.

The Arrival model, where the filtered `SupplierInfo_substrate` should be saved.

```
class Arrival(models.Model):
    submitted_on = DateTimeField(auto_created=True, null=True, blank=False, editable=False)
    edited_on = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    submitted_by = ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    supplier = ForeignKey(Supplier, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    arrival_date = DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=False) 
    substrate = ManyToManyField(Substrate, blank=True)
```

The Substrate and Supplier models, which are connected to `Arrival` and `Supplier`.

```
class Substrate(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=299, unique=True, null=True, blank=False)
    
class Supplier(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=299, unique=True, null=True, blank=False)
```

The SupplierInfo model, from which supplier and its substrate should be filtered.

> Note: One supplier can have multiple substrates. Simply, filtering supplier returns multiple query set each with a different `substrate (ForeignKey)` name.

```
class SupplierInfo(models.Model):
    supplier = ForeignKey(to=Supplier, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False)
    substrate = ForeignKey(to=Substrate, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True, blank=False)
    mushroom = ForeignKey(to=Mushrooms, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        null=True, blank=False)
    weight = FloatField(null=True,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0.9)],blank=False)
    yield_min = FloatField(null=True, 
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0.9), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    yield_max = FloatField(null=True, blank=True,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0.9), MaxValueValidator(100)],
        )
    status = BooleanField(null=True)
```

Comment: what is your question? This can only be done via Javascript and overwriting the existing admin-form. Maybe this gets you in the right direction.

Comment: What do you think about admin.StackedInline or TabularInline?

Comment: @Faulander "what is your question"? Let's say there are two countries, each country has it's own state. If I click on country "USA", then it's states should be filtered, and i should be able to click on it's states like: Massachusetts

Comment: probably https://github.com/jazzband/django-smart-selects is your best bet